# Automaticaly changing the url of my localhost

Tags: apache, xampp

When I click on the folder,  the url of the page is not like

`Localhost/login` but `www.localhost/login`.

What should i do to get it back?

1. Using xampp
2. Not using any `.htaccess` files

Comment: What folder are you clicking ?

Comment: I am clicking on the login folder. So it must show the index file. but it turns into www mode url .